# Jade templating : loop in attributes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, templating

I have a javascript object in my jade view like this :

```
element = {
    name: 'createdAt',
    type: 'text',
    attrs: {
        class: 'date',
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'Created at'
    }
}
```

I would like generate attributes on an input tag, trying something like this

```
input(
   each k, v in element.attrs
       k= v  
)
```

Of course this doesn't work, I also tried some inline code but without success.
Do you have any idea to help me ?

Comment: You could see here: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/664

Comment: Thx a lot :) I'm using a mixing for it and its ok !

Comment: @user290112 You could post your solution as an answer so other ppl could get the information as well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From documentation:

> Pronounced "and attributes", the &attributes syntax can be used to explode an object into attributes of an element.

```
div#foo(data-bar="foo")&attributes({'data-foo': 'bar'})
```

http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/#and-attributes